# Eclipse : Errors occurred during the build Groovy/Grail Project

Tags: eclipse, grails

I  have installed GGTS plugin for eclipse kepler 3.5.1 RELEASE. I created simple grail project. But while building project. Its getting error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'FirstApp'.
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

and if we saw in markers,  I found this error

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.plus(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/String; at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.transform.TransactionalTransform.moveOriginalCodeToNewMethod(TransactionalTransform.groovy:259)  
Config.groovy   /FirstApp/grails-app/conf   line 0  Java Problem
```

I am using feroda 17. Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Can you give the full stacktrace?

Comment: I am so sorry but it doesn't permit to build properly. Actually as i mentioned first error "Java builder" comes while building project. so I don't think so I would able to provide it. If there is another way then let me know to see stacktrace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were experiencing the same error today, it turned out that the project created by GGTS had a groovy compiler level of 2.3 but the GGTS plugin only supported up to groovy compiler level 2.1.

The fix was to install the "groovy 2.3 compiler for groovy-eclipse".

The compiler can be found under the "language and support tooling" heading in the extensions browser which is opened by clicking the "IDE extensions" button in the STS dashboard.

Although the compiler states that it will automatically become the default workspace compiler in eclipse this did not happen for us. In fact we needed to set it as the workspace default in "preferrences > groovy > compiler" and then restart eclipse (maybe I restarted twice, cant remember exactly).

we also ended up installing "groovy 2.3 compiler for groovy-eclipse" twice as the first time an eclipse IDE update was installed, I think because our kepler installation was a bit old.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly sir, It was issue regarding compiler versions. Thank you. GGTS plugin build according to 2.3 but if system has older version then this issue occures. There is another error Groovy : compiler mismatch Project level is 2.3 and Workspace level is 2.1 issue. above solution is applicable for both problems. :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: In GGTS 3.5.1, you can find this by opening the Dashboard (green/red icon in toolbar) and going to "Extensions" tab (bottom) then scrolling down to "Language and Framework Tooling"